# Holding shift to check multiple items in JS

Tags: javascript

I did another challenge by from Wes Bos JS course. This is my version, and I'll also post his version. Please let me know which one you think is better, thanks.

```js
const inbox = document.querySelector('.inbox');
let firstIndex = -1;
let shiftPressed = false;

function getIndex(parent, child) {
  return Array.from(parent.children).indexOf(child);
}

inbox.addEventListener('change', e => {
  const checkbox = e.target.closest('input[type="checkbox"]');
  if (!checkbox) return;

  const parent = checkbox.parentNode;
  const grandParent = parent.parentNode;
  if (!shiftPressed) {
    firstIndex = getIndex(grandParent, parent);
  } else {
    const secondIndex = getIndex(grandParent, parent);

    const grandChildren = grandParent.children;
    const [minIdx, maxIdx] = [Math.min(firstIndex, secondIndex), Math.max(firstIndex, secondIndex)];
    for (let idx = minIdx + 1; idx < maxIdx; idx++) {
      const itemDiv = grandChildren.item(idx);
      const itemCheckbox = itemDiv.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
      itemCheckbox.checked = true;
    }

    firstIndex = -1;
    shiftPressed = false;
  }
});

window.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if (e.shiftKey && firstIndex !== -1) {
    shiftPressed = true;
  }
});
```

```css
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #ffc600;
}

.inbox {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F1F1F1;
}

.item:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

input:checked+p {
  background: #F9F9F9;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  margin: 20px;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: background 0.2s;
  flex: 1;
  font-family: 'helvetica neue';
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 200;
  border-left: 1px solid #D1E2FF;
}
```

```html
<div class="inbox">
  <div class="item">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <p>This is an inbox layout.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <p>Check one item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <p>Hold down your Shift key</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <p>Check a lower item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <p>Everything in between should also be set to checked</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <p>Try to do it without any libraries</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <p>Just regular JavaScript</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <p>Good Luck!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <p>Don't forget to tweet your result!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is his JS code:

```js
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.inbox input[type="checkbox"]');

let lastChecked;

function handleCheck(e) {
  // Check if they had the shift key down
  // AND check that they are checking it
  let inBetween = false;
  if (e.shiftKey && this.checked) {
    // go ahead and do what we please
    // loop over every single checkbox
    checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
      console.log(checkbox);
      if (checkbox === this || checkbox === lastChecked) {
        inBetween = !inBetween;
        console.log('Starting to check them in between!');
      }

      if (inBetween) {
        checkbox.checked = true;
      }
    });
  }

  lastChecked = this;
}

checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => checkbox.addEventListener('click', handleCheck));
```